# Subset dataframe by checking equivalence of column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe for person X (who has the role 'A'):

```
Friend  Role
Alice   A
Bob     A
Cooper  B
Don     C
```

I want to subset this dataframe and keep only those rows where the friends also have the role 'A'. Moreover, if the person X has the role B or C, I want to keep rows where the role is not 'A'.

So if person X has A the result will be:

```
Friend  Role
Alice   A
Bob     A
```

If person X has role 'B' or 'C' the result will be:

```
Friend  Role
Cooper  B
Don     C
```

How can I achieve this in Python?

EDIT: Based on the answers, I realize I should be more specific. I don't want to hardcode the rules. Essentially, we can have an object 'PersonXRole' which can be A, B or C. Based on this object, the resulting dataframe should be filtered according to the rules defined above.

I was initially thinking something like:

```
if PersonXRole=='A':
   return (people with role A)
else:
   return (people with role B or C)
```

But Im not sure this is an efficient way of doing it

Comment: This seems like a basic task in Pandas, is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by a list of `X` possible roles, it is easier to pass 1 or more role options.

Now to validate the filter you're going to pass based on the role of the person you can apply a lambda function if you have two cases. Consider the example below

```
person_role = 'A'

# Determine which list to filter by 
fn_filter = lambda x: ['A'] if x == 'A' else ['B', 'C']

# Filter Friends roles of person_role
df[df.Role.isin(fn_filter(person_role))]
>>> 
    Friend  Role
0   Alice   A
1   Bob     A
```

or if `person_role = 'C'`

```
person_role = 'C'

df[df.Role.isin(fn_filter(person_role))]
>>> 
    Friend  Role
2   Cooper  B
3   Don     C
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specific. Please check the edit

Comment: @TheloniousMonk if you only have two cases, you can apply a lambda function to the person's role

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. Incase there are more than two cases (for example, a role D which should result in only role D persons, as well as roles E and F which result in only role E and F), how can this be tweaked?

Comment: @TheloniousMonk you could nest those cases, but it is someway unreadable for many cases. For example,  `fn_filter = lambda x: ['A'] if x == 'A' else (['D'] if x == 'D' else (['E'] if x == 'E' else (['F'] if x == 'F' else ['B', 'C'])))`

Answer (score 1):

Muliple ways to solve this, i usually go with slicing like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict({'Friend': {0: 'Alice', 1: 'Bob', 2: 'Cooper', 3: 'Don'},'Role': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}})

df_A = df[df["Role"]=="A"]

df_BC = df[(df["Role"]=="B") | (df["Role"]=="C")]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is reasonable, though I should have been more specific. Please check the edit.